# Haunted by one question in mod queue

Tags: support, status-completed

(strictly moderator stuff, nothing interesting)

Every time I use bottom moderator bar to cycle through pending flags queue sooner or later I get [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9307/spam-message-it-will-be-gone-soon).

Bottom bar is just empty, no flags that I can see, it's long deleted. Why does it want my attention all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darned gremlins. They get everywhere, chewing cables.

I've kicked said gremlin where it hurts.